# k8 cronjob docker/curlimages POST appends the headers to the Accept one

Tags: kubernetes, curl, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a cronjob that sends a POST request with a simple body:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: test-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 15
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: test-cron-job
            image: docker.io/curlimages/curl:latest
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            args:
            - '-X POST'
            - '-H "Content-Type: application/json"'
            - '-d "{\"greetings\": [\"hello\"]}"'
            - 'https://webhook.site/e4531e68-17ec-42bd-b7f9-e66ae12930bd'
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

The request goes through but the content type is not `application/json` and the header itself gets appended to the `accept` header.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>

100   151    0    91  100    60    321    212 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   535
```

It looks like the header (in this case Content-Type but any will do) gets appended to the `accept` header.

```
>  POST /e4531e68-17ec-42bd-b7f9-e66ae12930bd HTTP/1.1
> Host: webhook.site
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1-DEV
> Accept: */*
>  "Content-Type: application/json"
> Content-Length: 60
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
```

The resulting webhook.io request has these headers:

```
Headers
connection  close
content-type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
content-length  60
accept  */* "Content-Type: application/json"
user-agent  curl/8.0.1-DEV
host    webhook.site
```

Notice how the accept header has `*/* "Content-Type: application/json"`, why is this happening?